# how to read an hebrew text from a file

Tags: nsstring, hebrew

I want to read a text of hebrew from a file to nsstring object,I know the code line:

NSString *text=[NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:path encoding:encoding error:NULL];

i dont know what kind of file it have to be:rtf,xml or something else
and what  kind of encoding I have to use for hebrew

Answer (score 0):

UTF-8 is the proper encoding you want.

http://www.alanwood.net/unicode/hebrew.html

Comment: What other type of file is there besides text files ? If you format your text file using xml, json, or anything else, it is still a text file, and you read the raw bytes to a string the same way. What you do with that string is up to you.

Comment: does this file is have to be in he.lproj subdirectory?